# How to check what components an object consists of?

Tags: kotlin

When I receive an object, I want to know how to check what components the value consists of.

```
inputData?.let {
   val detail: MutableState<Any?> = mutableStateOf(null)
   detail.value = inputData
}
```

I want to read components of inputData.
I'd like to check how the components of input data are made.

---Edit

```
class SelectDetail (
    private val purchaseDao: PurchaseDao,
    private val purchaseEntityMapper: PurchaseEntityMapper
) {
    fun execute(
        type: String,
        id: Int
    ): Flow<DataState<Any>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(DataState.loading())
            when(type) {
                "purchase" -> {
                    val cacheResult = purchaseDao.getPurchaseById(id)
                    val data = purchaseEntityMapper.fromEntity(cacheResult)
                    emit(DataState.success(data))
                }
            }
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(DataState.error<Any>(e.message?: "Unknown Error"))
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

And then call from viewModel,

```
private fun selectDetail() {
    selectDetail.execute(type = type.value, id = detailId.value).onEach { dataState ->
        loading.value = dataState.loading

        dataState.data?.let { inputData ->
            -----In here-----
        }

        dataState.error?.let { error ->
            Log.d(TAG, "message: $error")
        }
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Here is the DataState

```
data class DataState<out T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: String? = null,
    val loading: Boolean = false,
) {
    companion object {

        fun <T> success(
            data: T
        ): DataState<T> {
            return DataState(
                data = data
            )
        }

        fun <T> error(
            message: String
        ): DataState<T> {
            return DataState(
                error = message
            )
        }

        fun <T> loading(): DataState<T> = DataState(loading = true)
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for the lack of explanation.

Comment: What is `inputData`? `Any?` ?

Comment: @ArpitShukla inputData is Any type object

Comment: And what do you mean by its `components`?

Comment: @ArpitShukla oops sorry , components mean it's property

Comment: Please add the code for `DataState` as well.